# How to remove a Automated Device Enrollment profile from macOS

Tags: macos, profile, mdm

First, show the profiles I have.

```
sudo profiles show -type enrollment
```

Second，remove all the profiles

```
sudo profiles remove -all
```

An error occurs:

```
profiles: There are profiles installed that marked non-removable
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found an answer here.
https://graffino.com/til/UmkCdmEx7v-remove-a-non-removable-mdm-profile-from-macos-without-a-complete-wipe

1. Boot the Mac into Recovery Mode (hold down command+R during startup).
2. Go to the Utilities menu and open Terminal and type: csrutil disable. This will disable SIP (System Integrity Protection).
3. Reboot into the OS.
4. Open the integrated terminal and type:

```
cd /var/db/ConfigurationProfiles
rm -rf *
mkdir Settings
touch Settings/.profilesAreInstalled
```

5. Reboot.
6. Boot the Mac into Recovery Mode (hold down command+R during startup).
7. Go to the Utilities menu and open Terminal and type: csrutil enable. This will re-enable SIP.
8. Reboot into the OS.

Comment: This worked for me with one modification. When executing rm -rf *, if you get "Permission denied", then prepend sudo. Ex: sudo rm -rf *

Comment: I wasn't able to reboot into the OS for steps 3 & 4 because I had formatted my HD. You can still do it by rebooting into recovery to access the terminal as in step 2, but then navigating to /Volumes/Machintosh HD/var/db/CondigurationProfiles before performing the subsequent commands. Everything else worked as required

Answer (score 2):

Suppression de profil MDM de supervision

 Supervision d’appareils Apple

1️⃣ Turn of system integrity

Shut down computer.
Boot up computer while holding (command + R)
Press ‘utilities’.
Type (csrutil disable)
Restart

2️⃣ Give terminal root files access

Open ‘Privacy and Security’ in ‘System Preferences’.
Press ‘Privacy’
Press ‘Complete Disk Access’
Unlock with the lock button at the bottom left
Add terminal.

3️⃣ Terminal Commands

Type: ‘sudo jamf -removeFramework’ into terminal, press enter.
Type: ‘sudo -i’ into terminal, press enter and enter your password, press enter.
Type: ‘cd /var/db/‘ into terminal, press enter.
Type: ‘mv ConfigurationProfiles ConfigurationProfilesOLD’ into terminal, press enter.
Type: ‘logout’ into terminal, press enter.

4️⃣ Final steps

Restart computer.